# Magento 2 - Overwrite di.xml for Core Cms module

Tags: magento2, xml, di

I've looked and looked, but can't find anything explaining what i need to do.

Problem is, i want to add an svg file to the image uploader in the WYSIWYG. I know i need to extend the ***core*** to do this, but im not sure how to go about it.

I've noticed in this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142139/magento-2-upload-svg-files) he is modding the vendor folder, which to be honest isn't the right way to go about it. However the following does need adding to the xml:

```
<item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
```

What i've done so far, is inside of a folder i've made i've done the following:

> app/code/Magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml

But obviously this doesn't do anything, if anyone knows how to just do the di.xml that would be awesome.

edit* Looks as though there might be a slight issue in regards to security with this. But i guess thats the issue with any uploads.

Comment: Would this answer work in this case? https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/127563/158

Comment: So I've basically got to create an entire module just to mod one line?

Comment: Yeah I think you will need to do this via a module either to extend the di.xml or to create a plugin for the `getAllowedExtensions` or something similar.